# Writing my age in decimal format

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write my age in decimal format (e.g. 28.232423424) in Javascript and have this number update in real time. An example of what I'm trying to do can be seen on [this page](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/life-hacks).

So far, I have the following:

**Javascript**

```
var age, daysBetweenDates;
daysBetweenDates = function(d1, d2) {
  var diffDays, firstDate, oneDay, secondDate;
  oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  firstDate = Date.parse(d1);
  secondDate = Date.parse(d2);
  diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
  return diffDays;
};

age = function() {
  var today;
  today = new Date();
  return $('#myAge').text(daysBetweenDates('Jun 2, 1987', today) / 365);
};

$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  return setInterval(age, 500);
});
```

I am getting a number 28.27123287671233 (which I believe is correct). However, despite setting an interval of half a second (500 milliseconds) I am not seeing my age update as it does on the example link I referred to above.
Am I thinking about this algorithm incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you calculate the days and round it afterwards.
Remove the rounding part and it works as you expect.

I tweaked your code a little:

```
var age, daysBetweenDates;
daysBetweenDates = function(d1, d2) {
  var diffDays, oneDay;
  oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  diffDays = (d2 - Date.parse(d1)) / oneDay;
  return diffDays;
};

age = function() {
  $('#myAge').text(daysBetweenDates('Jun 2, 1987 00:00:00', new Date()) / 365);
};

setInterval(age, 500);
```

JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qm4dudr7/